# How can I monitor my validator, other than using validator logs?

Tags: rust, solana-cli, validator, solana-test-validator

I want to monitor my validator for development purpose. I want to see `debug logs`

```
debug!("CUDA ECDSA for {}", valid_packet_count);
debug!("allocating out..");
```

And this `trace logs`

```
trace!("Starting verify num packets: {}", num_packets);
trace!("elem len: {}", elems.len() as u32);
trace!("packet sizeof: {}", size_of::<Packet>() as u32);
trace!("len offset: {}", PACKET_DATA_SIZE as u32);
```

and various performance measures and metrics such as

```
let (result, recv_time_us) = measure_us!({
```

like this `measure_us!` macro , to get performace stats for each section

cause in the solana-validator-logs I can only find which is logged by `info` macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable various log levels like so:

```
export RUST_LOG=DEBUG
```

You can also specify different log levels for a comma-separated list of modules:

```
export RUST_LOG=solana_bpf_loader=debug,solana_runtime::system_instruction_processor=trace
```

More info: https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/#enabling-logging